# JQuery - perform operations on the same object preventing the overwriting

Tags: jquery

I have 2 form select. 
I would check the value of the select on change and if the value is 2 I'd like to disable the same div.

HTML

```
<select id="foo">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="bar">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$('select#foo').change(function()
{
var eck = $('select#foo option:selected').prop('value');

    if (eck == '2')
    {
        $('#div').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#div').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});

$('select#bar').change(function()
{
var eck = $('select#bar option:selected').prop('value');

    if (eck == '2')
    {
        $('#div').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#div').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

My problem is that in this way on change event of each select this over- writes that previous. 
How could I do to handle this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is, if `option[value=2]` is selected in either of the `select` elements then disable the element with id `div`. So

```js
var $selects = $('#foo, #bar').change(function() {
  $('#div').prop('disabled', $selects.find('[value="2"]').is(':selected'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="foo">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="bar">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<button id="div">div</button>
```